# Integrate additional Libraries - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

I am adding an external library :-

```
implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:X.Y.Z'
```

and I am adding this dependency to my build.gradle file in app module. After successfully syncing the project, when I add that particular dependency in my xml file, it is not working. I used the following code:-

```
<com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker
    android:id="@+id/ccp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

This is showing the following error:-

```
Class referenced in the layout file, com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker, was not found in the project or the libraries
Cannot resolve class com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker
```

Also while calling the private Country Code in JAVA file, it is showing errors. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `X.Y.Z` should be a particular dependency version,
the latest version I can see is `2.5.4`, as mentioned on library's repository.

You should be adding the dependency like this:

```
implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.5.4'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  It really helped me.

Comment: Please accept as an Answer if it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

instead of X.Y.Z. you should put a version number like this

```
implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.5.4'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  It really helped me.

Comment: If this answer works for you. accept the answer, please